# Growing Goji berry plant in Ohio

Tags: planting, overwintering

I am entertaining the idea of growing a Goji berry plant in my backyard.  I have several fruit trees already and have good soil conditions.  The plant would be permanently outdoors and would not be brought in during the winter.  I live in Northeast Ohio (Zone 6) and so winters can get a little harsh.

1. Can Goji berry plants survive an Ohio winter?
2. Does anything special need to be done to winterize them?
3. Is there any kind of special soil prep or maintenance that should be done?
4. Is this plant a complete waste of time?  ;)

Answer (score 4):

They are very hardy, and will survive in zone 5 or so... There have been feral populations in northern Utah since the railroad was joined... Most of the Goji plants in the US market are from this stock from one supplier in northern Utah.
I have grown them for a few years, and have been surprised with how many berries I get from such small plants, but the berries themselves don't taste like much... Maybe they will get sweeter and more tart when the plant gets bigger.

Comment: Oh and for wintering, I just left them staked up, they are supposed to become self supporting in a few years, but mine are still spindly.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Which state do you live in, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: I am in 6b/7a Salt Lake City. It usually doesn't get below 10-15f, but this winter has been ugly.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry I can't just add a comment yet. But I can  say that ours do fine in zone six. Winters have been mild the last few years but they are happy. I have a fence of sorts around them and this helps support the snow when there is lots. I understand they can have a good sized root system when growing strong. 
We dry them and use them in smothies.

Answer (score 1):

I have one growing in zone 4.5 (upper Midwest) without trouble. It did take several years here to really establish, as it would die back almost to the ground each winter. Now it is rather large and no longer dies back, even with the harsh winters we had a few years ago.

I do nothing to winterize it at this point. Early on, I did cage it to prevent rodent damage on the winter. It is a trouble-free plant at this point.

The berries on my plant are intensely flavored and astringent and I enjoy them. I think there is great variability to the flavor of the plants you can buy, as I've heard other growers describe them as everything from bland to delicious.